# How do I put a command on VB2012 that works when I try to exit?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I want to make a form to ask you if you would like to save before exiting. How do I do this? I'm using Visual Studio 2012 and somehow have basic knowledge.

Comment: Add a handler for the Form Closing Event: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosing(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Just handle the FormClosing Event

```
Private Sub myForm_FormClosing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    If MessageBox.Show("Would you like to save before exiting?", "Close", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes Then
'do save stuff here
    Else
      e.Cancel = True
    End If
  End Sub
```